# UINavigationController bar button Trigger

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How can I trigger when a bar button is clicked in UINavigationController?

As I need to reset the image in the details view when the bar button item "Back" is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit vague. 2 possible answers.

1. Link the bar button item in IB to a method in your view controller object that does the reset when clicked.
2. I assume you want to reset something when the view controller unloads or disappears.  You will want to see -()viewdidunload. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since my app root controller is UINavigationController, when I navigate to the details view controller and press back button it will not unload the details view, I put an alert in viewdidunload() and it wasn't triggered! Regarding your first suggestion, in IB the back button is not there!

Comment: hmmm, ok not sure if you where popping back to a different view why that would not work, makes sense that it does not have the back button in IB. Maybe try (void)viewWillDisappear: and see if that works. Also some of your code would assist in clarifying.

Comment: Dear @daltoniam, many thanks for your follow-up, also viewWillDisappear was not triggered when I press BACK button! I don't know which part of my code will help to share here, I followed this tutorial to create app structure http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/06/tab-bars-and-navigation-bars-t.html and I followed this tutorial to load the image in the details view http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image

Comment: I looked at the examples. I pretty sure the view will unload or will disappear should work. I would have to see your tableview controllers to figure out why they don't trigger.